# What size tyres will fit my wheel?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, wheels, size

My bike wheel was recently stolen and I found this old Bontrager AT-550 wheel in my shed. It's a 29er from my research and I'm wondering what size tyre would fit that would be decently smaller than the current tyre. My bike is a hybrid with a 700cx42c back tyre and the front tyre is 29x2.2 and it would look ridiculous to have a big tyre in the front and small one in the back. I'm sorry for mixing the units the measurement but I'm new to this and would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: A 29" rim is the same diameter as a 700c rim.  The 42 number on your back tire is its (approximate) width in mm and equals 1.65 inches.  The difference between 1.65 and 2.2 is not enormous -- it might look a little odd.  The bigger question is whether the wider tire and (probably) wider rim will cause clearance problems with fork or brake, and the easiest way to tell that is to try it, if you have the wheel in your hands already.

Comment: Don't apologize for not understanding bicycle wheel sizes.  No one understands them....

Comment: I'm currently using 29er MTB rims with 700c x 35 tires. I'd say that unles your rim is unusually wide, It will fit a tire of this size or wider with no issues.

Comment: @mattnz - Yep, a 27" inch rim is larger than a 29" rim.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks Thank you for the answer. I have read online that the maximum tyre size that would fit on my bike is 47c. The real question is what size tyre will fit on the rim. Does it make any difference? I've read online that as long as the tyre isnt way smaller than the width of the rim then it should work fine. So I was looking into getting the same size tyre to the back to make it look less odd. Ive tried fitting the wheel already and it seems to work just fine. I now need to order a tube, quick release skewer and tyre. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: Read the duplicates.

Comment: Yes that helps quite a bit. I measured it to be 24mm though and the scale goes up in odd numbers. Does that make a huge difference if I just go with the 23 or 25 reading? Never mind, both support 44 so Im guessing 24 will do too. Thanks again!